# Generate arrows in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to generate simple arrowheads at the end of each line using `.append("svg:marker")`  . I'm obviously doing something wrong - help very much appreciated.

[A link to bl.ocks example .](http://bl.ocks.org/jalapic/84356b24081885132bd5)

```js
var svg = d3.select("body") // select the 'body' element
      .append("svg")           // append an SVG element to the body
      .attr("width", 600)      
      .attr("height", 600);   


d3.csv("data/myarrows.csv", dottype1, function(error, lines) {
  
svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("line")
      .data(lines)
      .enter()
      .append("line")
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.x1; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.y1; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.x2; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.y2; })
      .style("stroke", "brown")           // colour the line
      .style("stroke-width", 4)          // adjust line width
      .style("stroke-linecap", "square") // stroke-linecap type
      

svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("marker")
      .data(lines)
      .enter()
      .append("svg:marker") 
      .attr('viewBox', '0 -5 10 10')
        .attr('refX', 6)
        .attr('markerWidth', 10)
        .attr('markerHeight', 10)
        .attr('orient', 'auto')
        .append('svg:line')
        .attr('d', 'M0,-5L10,0L0,5')
                 ;
});




function dottype1(d) {
  d.x1 = +d.x1x1;
  d.y1 = +d.y1y1;
  d.x2 = +d.x2x2;
  d.y2 = +d.y2y2;
   return d;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Arrows</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

</head>


<body>    
  
<script type="text/javascript">

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few things wrong:

1. You only need one marker, which you then reference by its id. See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/SVG/Element/marker).
2. The marker should be in a `defs` instead of a `g`, but it's not really important.
3. You use `line` instead of `path`, but only `path` has the `d` attribute.

In code, this means:

```
svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("line")
      .data(lines)
      .enter()
      .append("line")
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.x1; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.y1; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.x2; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.y2; })
      .attr("marker-end", "url(#triangle)") // add the marker
      .style("stroke", "brown")           // colour the line
      .style("stroke-width", 4)          // adjust line width
      .style("stroke-linecap", "square") // stroke-linecap type
               ;

svg.append("svg:defs")
      .append("svg:marker") 
      .attr("id", "triangle")
      .attr('viewBox', '0 -5 10 10')
      .attr('refX', 6)
      .attr('markerWidth', 10)
      .attr('markerHeight', 10)
      .attr('orient', 'auto')
      .append('svg:path')
        .attr('d', 'M0,-5L10,0L0,5')
                 ;
});
```

I didn't test this code however, I only tried this manually in the devtools.